# "Отчистить" и "очистить": выбор слова

Tags: семантика, глаголы, приставка, паронимы, значение

Правильно ли употреблено слово *отчистить*? Я ранее думал, что так писать ошибочно, но нашел пояснение на [сайте](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/kak-pravilno-govorit-ochistit-ili-otchistit.html), что *отчистить* в отличие от *очистить* несет значение более *тщательной уборки с применением физических усилий*...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Толковый словарь С.И.Ожегова:

> ОТЧИСТИТЬ, -ищу, -истишь; -ищенный; сов., что.
>
> 1. Чистя, удалить
>    что-н. О. пятно.
> 2. Сделать чистым, удалив грязь, что-н. наросшее, налипшее. О. свою одежду. О. котелок от копоти. II несов. отчищать, -аю, -аешь. II
>    возвр. отчиститься, -ищусь, -исти

Видимо, данное чистящее средство способно не просто очистить грязные сковороды, а именно отчистить от них (удалить) что-то наросшее и налипшее, которое не очищается обычным средством и требует больших усилий. Так что слово употреблено верно.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ли сказать в рекламном тексте: ***очистить сковороды и кастрюли***? Без дополнительного указания (*от чего будем чистить*) звучит странно и неопределенно.

Вообще говоря, **частотность** многозначного глагола  "очистить" намного выше, чем "отчистить" (2800:40). Можно очистить всё, в том числе квартиру, карманы, а также  сковороды, кастрюли и холодильники от их содержимого.

А вот глагол "отчистить" вполне **конкретен** и больше подходит для чистящего средства.

**ОТЧИСТИТЬ,** -св. что. Чистя, удалить. О. **пятно.** О. ржавчину. // Удалив **грязь, пятно**, сделать чистым. О. свою одежду. О. раковину, посуду.